# Objective-C clang-format for blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang-format

I've scoured google and tinkered with my .clang-format file for hours now.

I want my blocks to look like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    label.alpha = 0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    label.hidden = YES;
}];
```

Not this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    label.alpha = 0;
}
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        label.hidden = YES;
    }];
```

I can't seem to find the right parameter or group of parameters.

I also gave Uncrustify a shot but staring over with a new config file syntax isn't preferable, especially if there is a clang-format solution.

Comment: Remove the newline after the first block and use space instead,

Answer (score -3):

```
// clang-format off

[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{

} completion:^(BOOL finished){

}];
// clang-format on
```